# Twitter Bootstrap Navbar and Marketing Area

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make my first Bootstrap project. Using Bootstrap 2.

my problem is in the navbar and the marketing area.

1. The navbar should be horizontal right? What am I doing wrong?
2. The marketing area should have a greyish background right? Why is it not showing here.

Here's part of the code I am working at:

```
<div class="container banner-header">
    <h1><a href="#">Argyle's Automobile</a></h1>
 </div>

 <!--Navbar-->
 <div class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Social</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
</div>

<!--Marketing Area-->
<div class="container">
<div class="hero-unit">
    <h1>Marketing stuff!</h1>

    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-success">Get Started</a>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You're using bootstrap 3 in that image, not 2. This is how it should look: http://jsfiddle.net/BVmUL/442/

Comment: Oh. Thank you Adrift. Got it now. Downloaded the v2.3.2 instead.